# How to extract html attributes via regex

Tags: regex

I am looking to see how a regex can be used to get attribute/values from an html tag. Yes I know that an xml/html parser can be used, but this is for testing my ability in regex. For example, in this html element:

```
<input name=dir value=">">
<input value=">" name=dir >
```

How would I extract out:

```
(?<name>...) and (?<value>...)
```

Is it possible once you have matched something to go "back" to the start of the match? For example:

```
<(?P<element>\w+).+(?:value="(?P<value>[^"])")@@@@.+(?:name="(?P<name>[^"])")
```

Where `@@@@` basically means "go back to the start of the previous match/capture group (so that I don't have to modify every possible ordering of the tags). How could this be done?

Comment: `value=">"`: where did you see that?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte could you please clarify your comment?

Comment: Pretty sure this question is referring to the exact reason why this doesn't work. The whole go back to the start of the previous string is what a pushdown automaton does. Something regular languages I.e. regex, cannot handle.

Comment: @AER I see. So basically you'd need to do some sort of combinatorics for this to work for all the possible positions?

Comment: It's a bit of a hunch, I'm not a CS student. But it's something that requires memory. Regex only uses what it's presented with. It doesn't go back and go remember what it did on the previous step. I'd turn this into an answer if I knew more, because this is actually a great example I suspect to highlight why it doesn't work.

Comment: See this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy

And note the memory used by all the different machines that create the different languages.

Comment: You can't, see [... FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7505395) - thats why parsers exist. If you want to train regex, try [https://regexcrossword.com/](https://regexcrossword.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, using a parser is the best way.
2. As stated in the comments, you cannot (easily) extract all information in one sweep.
3. You can achieve what you want with several regexes:

```
input.*?name=(?'name'[^ ]+)
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/KL7oYm/1).

```
input.*?value="(?'value'[^"]+)"
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/tnl7du/1).